# INARMA proces in R

Tags: r, arma

I have time series of with integer value numbers. I want to test if my process is Integer Valued AR(1) pocess or similar integer valued ARMA process in R. Could somebody provide me with any ideas how should I indicate what integer valued process it might be?

Thanks!

Comment: Asking for R code / functions is off topic here. If you have a statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: How statistically I could test if my data is Integer valued arma process? What would be the difference between integer valued arma and arma?

Answer (score 1):

You can see immediately whether the process is integer valued or not; if its realization contains anything else besides integers, it is not an integer-valued process; if it contains only integers, then it is likely an integer-valued process (only "likely" because another realization could perhaps have a non-integer realization). If you know what subject-matter phenomenon that process represents, the answer should be even clearer.

The remaining question is, is it an (integer) ARMA process? You might not be able to answer that question precisely, but you could evaluate how well an INARMA model approximates the process. When you fit an INARMA model, you may use model diagnostics to evaluate its appropriateness. I am no expert of INARMA models, but I would look at the assumptions underlying the model and, given a fitted model, try to test whether they hold. If they do, you could say that INARMA approximates the process well; if they don't, the conclusion is the opposite. If there are a few competing models, their diagnostics and their AIC or BIC values could be compared to see which one offers the best approximation.